# Index like in glossaries-user

Tags: glossaries, indexing, xindy

I would like to create an index as it can be found in [glossaries-user.pdf](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf).

**Precise goal:** A glossary for acronyms and an index in which all acronyms are listed (though only for selected pages) in addition to other terms. The index should have its pagenumbers colored, right aligned in two balanced columns, with dots filling the gap between the term and the page numbers.

**Current attempt**: Currently [glossaries](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) is used for the glossary and I plan on using an indexing package for the index with `xindy` and a style file.

**Problem**: While I am not sure about the correct style definition, I get the error message `undefined controlsequence \lettergroup` as soon as I use the example style file

MWE:

```
\documentclass{muthesis}

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[options={-M indexStyle}]

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    ASd\index{asd}

    \lipsum

    \index{end}

    \printindex
\end{document}
```

Stylefile (based on `makeidx.xdy` from `xindy`, commented out lines that just caused warnings/errors):

```
;; $Id: makeidx.xdy,v 1.1 1997/02/07 14:17:31 kehr Exp $
;;
;; This file implements the Output Style Specifiers for plain
;; makeindex (see manpage of makeindex 2.x) in conjuction with
;; TeX/LaTeX.
;;
;; The Input Style Specifiers of makeindex cannot de defined in a
;; `xindy' style file. Use an appropriate version of the program
;; `tex2xindy' which should be included with this distribution.
;;
;; Since `xindy' uses a different specification language than
;; makeindex and some of the command-line options of makeindex are now
;; only available as style-file commands, this file can only serve as
;; a template that produces the default-markup of makeindex. However,
;; it may be used as a starting point for further modification and
;; specialization.
;;
;; The following values are taken from the source of the makeindex
;; distribution (see file scanst.h and the manpage) for further
;; details.
;;

;; Define all attributes appearing in your document. Your attributes
;; are all encapsulators you use in your \index commands following the
;; vertical bar sign `|'. For example `foo' is the attribute in the
;; command \index{...|foo}. Here you specify the set of attributes
;; that appear in your document, the order in which they appear in the
;; index and which one superdes the other.
;;
;; Example: a) (define-attibutes (("default") ("bf") ("it")))
;;          b) (define-attibutes (("bf" "default")))
;;
;; The initial command is (change it accordingly):

;; (define-attributes (("default")))

;; The description of the location-classes.
;; Add more location classes as needed.

;; (define-location-class "arabic-page-numbers" ("arabic-numbers"))
;; (define-location-class "roman-page-numbers"  ("roman-numbers-lowercase"))
;; (define-location-class "Roman-page-numbers"  ("roman-numbers-uppercase"))
;; (define-location-class "alpha-page-numbers"  ("alpha"))
;; (define-location-class "Alpha-page-numbers"  ("ALPHA"))

;; The most frequently used cross reference class "see". Add more, if
;; necessary.

;; (define-crossref-class "see")
;; (markup-crossref-list :open "\see{" :close "}{}" :class "see")

;; In makeindex: page_precedence <string>  "rnaRA"
;; List all location classes appearing in your document.

(define-location-class-order ("roman-page-numbers"
                  "arabic-page-numbers"
                  "alpha-page-numbers"
                  "Roman-page-numbers"
                  "Alpha-page-numbers"
                  "see"))


;; preamble <string>        "\\begin{theindex}\n"
;; postamble <string>       "\n\n\\end{theindex}\n"

(markup-index :open  "\begin{theindex}~n"
          :close "~n~n\end{theindex}~n"
          :tree)

;; These specifiers are not directly supported via a command-line
;; switch as in makeindex. Add the appropriate markup-commands into
;; the preamble.

;; setpage_prefix <string>  "~n  \setcounter{page}{"
;; setpage_suffix <string>  "}~n"

;; group_skip <string>      "~n~n  \indexspace~n"

(markup-letter-group-list :sep "~n~n  \indexspace~n")

;; The indexentries (item_<..> specifiers)

(markup-indexentry :open "~n  \item "           :depth 0)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n    \subitem "      :depth 1)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n      \subsubitem " :depth 2)

;; Location-references

;; delim_0 <string>         ", "
;; delim_1 <string>         ", "
;; delim_2 <string>         ", "

(markup-locclass-list :open ", " :sep ", ")

;; delim_n <string>         ", "

(markup-locref-list   :sep ", ")

;; delim_r <string>         "--"

(markup-range :sep "--")

;; Here follow all letter-groups. The short-cut notation is used here.

(define-letter-groups
    ("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m"
     "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"))

;;
;; The sort-rules map all letters to their lowercase counterpart.
;;

(sort-rule "A" "a")
(sort-rule "B" "b")
(sort-rule "C" "c")
(sort-rule "D" "d")
(sort-rule "E" "e")
(sort-rule "F" "f")
(sort-rule "G" "g")
(sort-rule "H" "h")
(sort-rule "I" "i")
(sort-rule "J" "j")
(sort-rule "K" "k")
(sort-rule "L" "l")
(sort-rule "M" "m")
(sort-rule "N" "n")
(sort-rule "O" "o")
(sort-rule "P" "p")
(sort-rule "Q" "q")
(sort-rule "R" "r")
(sort-rule "S" "s")
(sort-rule "T" "t")
(sort-rule "U" "u")
(sort-rule "V" "v")
(sort-rule "W" "w")
(sort-rule "X" "x")
(sort-rule "Y" "y")
(sort-rule "Z" "z")


;; That's all ;-)


;; End

;; Local Variables:
;; mode: lisp
;; End:
```

What the index should look like:
[image: What the index should look like]

**Rational/What I tried**: Since I would like a index as in the user guide, the best solution would be to copy the method. However, when I tried to create the user guide from the sources the index did not show up. I assume I have to run `texindy` with specific parameters, (as is needed for the glossaries-code.pdf but could not find instructions for the generation. Furthermore, it seems to me that the index code is anchored in the `nctldoc` class, and I am forced to use the `muthesis` class. As the author of `glossaries` prefers the use of an external indexing package, I assumed that it would make sense to use an indexing package. Furthermore, I am unsure how I would use the term in the Acronym and the index glossary. While there is a [solution to make a glossary term only add selected page numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290614/19326), using an explicit index package seems more straight forward.

I do not care which indexing package to use, currently I am trying `imakeidx` with `xindy` and a style file.

Comment: If I had to rewrite `glossaries-user.tex`, I'd probably use `bib2gls` instead. (It's too big a task and not worth the effort.) If you want to stick with `makeindex` or `xindy`, then using the `glossaries-extra` extension package is better for this type of thing.

Comment: You seem to be asking two questions: (1) how to have a term appear in both a glossary list (e.g. list of abbreviations) and in the index, which I've answered, and (2) how to adjust the non-glossary index style.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: I am actually most interested in (2), I don't want  every use of `\gls{myAcronym}` to appear in the index. While you have an [excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290614/19326) for this, I am under the expression that it is better to use an actual index package for the index, rather than glossaries. My rational for this is that you, the Queen of glossaries, seem to use `makeidx` over the `index` glossaries option. This leads to my formatting question for the index. However, I wanted to avoid the XY problem, and leave the option of using glossaries ...

Comment: ... which then changes the index formating problem from a xindy problem into a formatting a glossarie problem. While, I had no issues with changing glossaries format, it seems to me that using `imakeidx` is the right tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The index should have its pagenumbers colored, right aligned in two
>   balanced columns, with dots filling the gap between the term and the
>   page numbers.

This can be achieved as follows:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{indexStyle.xdy}
(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill " :sep "\dotfill ")
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{muthesis}

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeindex[options={-M indexStyle}]

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    ASd\index{asd}

    \lipsum

    \index{end}

    \printindex
\end{document}
```

The index looks like:

[image: image of index]

For automatically indexing glossary entries, you could trying using the `indexname` and `dualindex` attributes. The example file [`sample-autoindex.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/samples/sample-autoindex.tex) provided with `glossaries-extra` uses this method:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[abbreviations,counter=chapter,nopostdot=false]{glossaries-extra}

\renewcommand*{\abbreviationsname}{List of Abbreviations}
\renewcommand*{\glossarypreamble}{\emph{Numbers refer to the 
\textbf{chapter} where the entry was referenced.}}

\makeindex
\makeglossaries

% Automatically index the location of entry in the glossary
% for those entries that are in the "general" category:

\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{indexname}{textbf}
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{dualindex}{true}

% Only index first use for the glossary location lists
% (doesn't affect the indexing from "dualindex" attribute):
%\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{indexonlyfirst}{true}

% Automatically index the location of entry in the glossary
% for those entries that are in the "abbreviation" category
% and use "textbf" as the encap:

\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{indexname}{textbf}
\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{dualindex}{true}

% Only index first use for the glossary location lists
% (doesn't affect the indexing from "dualindex" attribute):
%\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{indexonlyfirst}{true}

% Convert the first letter of the name to upper case in the 
% glossary for general entries:
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossname}{firstuc}

% Allow "format" key to override "dualindex" attribute.
\GlsXtrEnableIndexFormatOverride

% use first field instead of name field
\renewcommand*{\glsxtrautoindexentry}[1]{\string\glsentryfirst{#1}}

% use long form for the sort value, if provided:
\renewcommand*{\glsxtrautoindexassignsort}[2]{%
  \ifglshaslong{#2}%
  {\glsletentryfield{#1}{#2}{long}}%
  {\glsletentryfield{#1}{#2}{sort}}%
}

% Define general entries:

\newglossaryentry{duck}{name=duck,%
  description={a waterbird with webbed feet}}

\newglossaryentry{parrot}{name=parrot,%
  description={mainly tropical bird with bright plumage}}

\newglossaryentry{at}{name={@},%
  description={makeindex's default for the ``actual value''}}

\newglossaryentry{esc}{name={"},%
  description={makeindex's default for the ``escape value''}}

\newglossaryentry{level}{name={!},%
  description={makeindex's default for the ``level value''}}

\newglossaryentry{encap}{name={|},%
  description={makeindex's default for the ``encap value''}}

% Set abbreviation style:

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-sc}

% Define abbreviations:

\newabbreviation
 {html}% identifying label
 {html}% short form
 {hypertext markup language}% long form

\newabbreviation
 {xml}% identifying label
 {xml}% short form
 {extensible markup language}% long form

\title{Sample document testing the glossaries-extra package}
\author{Nicola Talbot}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter{Introduction}

This is a sample\index{sample} document testing the
\texttt{glossaries-extra} package.

\chapter{General Entries}

Sample entries: \gls{duck} and \gls{parrot}.

Test makeindex's special characters: \gls{at} (actual)
\gls{esc} (escape) \gls{level} (level) and \gls{encap} (encap).

\chapter{Abbreviations}

First use: \gls{html} and \gls{xml}.

Next use: \gls{html} and \gls{xml}.

\newpage

Uses some entries again: \gls{duck} and \gls[format=textit]{parrot}.

\printglossaries

\printindex

\end{document}
```

The `dualindex` attribute is boolean. If `true` then whenever an entry is referenced with commands like `\gls` then it's also indexed with `\index`. For example `\gls{duck}` additionally does `\index{duck}`. If the `indexonlyfirst` attribute is set (commented out in the above) then only the first use of `\gls` (or variants) is accompanied by `\index`.

The `indexname` attribute, if set, indicates that the entry's place in the glossary should be indexed with `\index`. The value of this attribute may either be `true` (indexed with no encap) or the encap value. For example, the value `textbf` means that when the entry `duck` shows up in the glossary it should be indexed with `\index{duck|textbf}`. Since the glossary doesn't exist on the first LaTeX run, the index can't be fully created until after the glossary exists, so if `indexname` is used, then the build process needs to be:

```
pdflatex sample-autoindex
makeglossaries sample-autoindex
pdflatex sample-autoindex
makeindex sample-autoindex
pdflatex sample-autoindex
```

The actual part used in `\index` is obtained from `\glsxtrautoindexentry{`*label*`}`. By default this uses `\glsentryname` to match the way the term is displayed in the glossary. In the above, this is changed to use `\glsentryfirst`, which is the way the term appears on first use.

The sort part used in `\index` is assigned using `\glsxtrautoindexassignsort{`*cs*`}{`*label*`}`, where *cs* is the control sequence used to store the sort value. In the above, I've redefined it to use the long form if set. This means that abbreviations are sorted by their long form.

The `\gls` command (and its variants) allows the default encap used in the glossary to be changed with the `format` key. You can ensure that this encap is copied over to `\index` with

```
\GlsXtrEnableIndexFormatOverride
```

For example, with this set, `\gls[format=textbf]{duck}` does `\index{duck|textbf}` otherwise it would just do `\index{duck}`.

The complete document is [`sample-autoindex.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/samples/sample-autoindex.pdf)

The glossary looks like:

[image: image of glossary]

The list of abbreviations:

[image: image of list of abbreviations]

The index:

[image: image of index]

If you want to use `hyperref`, have a look at [`sample-autoindex-hyp`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/samples/sample-autoindex-hyp.tex) instead

Comment: I think my question was poorly written, I tired to clarify: **Main issue**: How to get an index that looks like the one in your userguide. *Sidenote*: I am early enoguh in the flow to switch packages, but am currently trying to do the index with `imakeidx` and `xindy`. +1 for the excellent answer though

Comment: @ted Sorry I misunderstood. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Not your fault, after all I could have just asked for the styling. Thanks for the quick reply.